# Pythonで非表示にしたwarningを再表示させたい

Tags: python, python3

**行いたいこと**
Python3で一時的にFuture Warning(`XX will be deprecated`...という警告)を一時的に非表示にし、所定の作業が終わったら、手動でまた再表示させたいです。

**現状**
`warnings.simplefilter('ignore', FutureWarning)`を行えば非表示にできることはわかりましたが、再表示させるコマンドを検索で見つけることができていません。

**現状の詳細**

- 本警告が出るのが特定のライブラリ（`X`とします）をimportした時です。
- 今行っている作業では「複数の.pyファイルを読み込んで、その中に定義されている関数を使う」ということをしています。その「複数の.py」のほぼ全てで、`import X`をしています。そのため各.pyを読み込むたびに警告メッセージが出力されてしまい、コマンド出力が警告メッセージで埋まってしまい必要な情報が見にくくなっています。
- パッケージ`X`の方で将来のバージョンに対応した設定に切り替えれば良いかと思いましたが、一度python3を`> exit()`すると設定が戻ってしまいます。（`X`ライブラリにも問い合わせたところ「pythonをローンチするたびにデフォルトに戻る設定になってしまっている」とのことでした）

Comment: この記事が参考になりそうです。[Enable all warnings in Python, after they were disabled by an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43832981/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考になりました。ただ、こちらを使おうとして非表示にするところから試したのですが、そもそも非表示にすることができないという問題が発生してしまいました。問題が違うようなので、少し試しても解決しなければ、一度こちらの質問は解決したとして閉じたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kunifさんより頂いた回答

> この記事が参考になりそうです。[Enable all warnings in Python, after they were disabled by an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43832981/9014308)

が有効そうであるため、一度この質問を閉じるため自己回答します。
なお、動作を試したかったのですが、そもそも警告メッセージを非表示にできないという問題が新たに発生しており、ライブラリ作成者に問い合わせたところライブラリの都合によるかもしれないとのことでしたので、本質問は一度閉じたいと思います。